# Partition remains as read only

Tags: partitioning, mount, gparted

I just switched from Windows over to Ubuntu 18.04 and I am trying to get my internal drives set up. I have one SSD that has the os on it and a second larger SSD that I am trying to format.

To start I changed the format to ext4 using `gparted`. The drive formatted and then I was successfully able to mount the drive to a folder I had created. However this drive was in read-only mode.

In my research I found that I shouldn't be using the following command to open `gparted`:

```
sudo gparted
```

The reason being that there can be some problems with how the permissions are handed down when creating the partition. I then found that I could use this modified command to fix the problem:

```
sudo -H gparted
```

The documentation says this about -H.

```
The -H (HOME) option requests that the security policy set the HOME 
environment variable to the home directory of the target user (root by 
default) as specified by the password database. Depending on the 
policy, this may be the default behavior.
```

The mount command I used was:

```
sudo mkdir /ssd
sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /ssd
```

It doesn't seem to output anything. The terminal just goes to the next line. However I can check inside of gparted to see that the drive has been mounted to the location I specified.

The error shows up when I try to create a new steam folder inside of the new drive:

[image: steam error]

Another thing that I noticed is that I am getting an error when launching gparted. An error comes up that says the following:

```
Unit -.mount does not exist, proceeding anyway.
```

I couldn't find a solution to this either and that might be related to why the drive is stuck.

Comment: Can you give us the output of and the exact `mount` command you're using?  Please [edit] your Q and then ping me @Fabby

Comment: @Fabby I am tagging here because I am not sure if I can tag in the question or not.

Comment: try unmounting, then `chown szUserName:szUserName /ssd` where `szUsername` is the user name of your user and then mount again.  Ping me again in the comments whether that solves your problem or not.

Comment: @Fabby Do I have to run that command with sudo? If I don't it says "operation not permitted"

Comment: Yes, sorry: sudo.

Comment: That leads to the same read only error after mounting and changing the permissions. Just to check that I entered the code right, if the username was bob I would enter    sudo chown bob:bob /ssd?

Comment: Correct.  I'm out of ideas now...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue. I can write to the drive now.

I followed the directions on this [wikihow](https://www.wikihow.com/Format-a-Hard-Drive-Using-Ubuntu) of all things

Thanks @Fabby for the help.